# How can I reward addresses with who add liquidity to the pool? (ERC20 token)

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, cryptocurrency, erc20

If an address swaps ETH for my_token, I wanna reward them with free my_tokens (calculated as a % of the transaction). Would it be possible to implement it in the solidity code or are there any built-in solutions on uniswap, pancakeswap etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it is usually done with liquidity mining.

- When you add liquidity you receive LP token of the pool (liquidity provider token(
- Then you lock these LP tokens to a vault
- As long as the LP tokens are locked, the user is receiving rewards

One of the most well-known contracts for such liquidity mining is [MasterCher from Sushiswap](https://etherscan.io/address/0xef0881ec094552b2e128cf945ef17a6752b4ec5d#code).

I suggest

- You try liquidity mining yourself by buying some token subject to liquidity mining
- Then see how MasterChef could be applied for your project